# Multiselect Picklist to Picklist conversion not showing any results in Apex

Tags: apex

Pick list categories (Field Type: Picklist multislect) it has 4 drop down values:

```
   Category 1
   Category 2
   Category 3
   Category 4
```

Category 4 present in Idea table:

[image]

Query returned:

```
 system.debug('Query------'+Query);  [Please Refer code in End]

select id,title,Stage__c,Categories,Image__c,NumComments,Body,status,createddate from idea Where Categories in('Category 4')
```

But no result values returned.

**Analysed:**

**But If only Category 4 present in Table Result will Appear. In the table it contains (Category 2,Category4) thats why result isnot coming.**

**Requirement:**

Converted Picklist multiselect to picklist in UI. Requirement here is **if any one value matches need to display that record.** [User cant select Category 2,Category 4 in one shot,he can select any one of the values at a time]

In above example category 4 present in Idea table but no results.

//**Instead of In keyword tried INCLUDES as well,but result is same**

```
   String Query = 'select id,title,Stage__c,Categories,Image__c,NumComments,Body,status,createddate from idea';
   boolean whereClauseAdded=false; 
       if (String.isNotBlank(categoryFilter)) {
                                              if(whereClauseAdded)
                                               query = query + ' AND Categories in('+ '\''+categoryFilter+'\'' +')'; 
                                              else
                                                  query=query+ 'Categories in('+ '\''+categoryFilter+'\'' +')';
                                              whereClauseAdded=true;
                                          } 

                                          system.debug('Query------'+Query);
                                          List<SObject> sObjectList = Database.query(Query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reviewing the detailed documentation on how to [query multi-select picklists in SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm).

There are at least two problems here. One is that you are using the incorrect syntax. To query a multi-select picklist based on a specific value being selected, you must use an `INCLUDES` clause. The following example is taken from the documentation:

> ```
> SELECT Id, MSP1__c from CustObj__c WHERE MSP1__c includes ('AAA;BBB','CCC')
> ```
>
> the query filters on values in the MSP1__c field that contains either of these values:
>
> - `AAA` and `BBB` selected.
> - `CCC` selected.
>
> A match will result on any field value that contains 'AAA' and 'BBB' or any field that contains 'CCC'.

The second problem is that your field data isn't valid for a multi-select picklist. In an MSP, selected picklist items are delimited by **semicolons** (`;`). Your screenshot clearly shows a value of `Category 2,Category 4`, delimited by a **comma**. SOQL will not understand this value as having the single picklist value `Category 4` selected.

If you've actually performed a conversion so that this field is no longer a multi-select picklist, you'd have to do yet a different query using `LIKE`, which is really not the right solution for what it appears you're trying to do.

Comment: I have used includes  but still same problem exist

Comment: Did you read the rest of the answer? There are at least two problems here.

Comment: Thanks David...

Comment: we use like keyword it through below error: System.QueryException: invalid operator on multipicklist field

Comment: As above, you would perform a `LIKE` query **If you've actually performed a conversion so that this field is no longer a multi-select picklist**.

Comment: i have done conversion in UI. But not in object level. i received above error

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what that means.